# Nested if statements in F#

Tags: f#, functional-programming

I have the following code

```
let rec function1 element1 element2 = function
        | [] -> []
        | [a;b;c;d;e;f]::t -> if true then if true then [a]::(function1 element1 element2 t) else (function1 element1 element2 t)
        | h :: t -> (function1 element1 element2 t);
```

,but it wont let me check if statement 1 and statement 2 is true

I keep getting

```
          | [a;b;c;d;e;f]::t -> if true then if true then [a]::(function1 element1 element2 t) else (function1 element1 element2 t)
  ------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

stdin(3,31): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    'a list    
but here has type
    unit
```

I tried many different things and it doesnt seem like i am trying something that shouldnt work. Help please

Answer (score 3):

You statement is read as:

```
if true
  then
    if true
      then something
      else somethingElse
  // missing else
```

If statement might omit `else` branch if type of overall expression should be `unit`. So when you omit `else` you can think of just adding `else ()` by the compiler.

On the other hand you are defining that `match` statement should return a list.

Answer (score 0):

As you have 2 if's but only 1 else branch, the compiler has inferred the return type to be unit as only 1 of the if expressions returns a non-unit.

You could fix this by either

1: remove the nesting - it's not necessary when you could && the conditions

2: add the extra else branch (which in you're case would return (function1 element1 element2 t))